# What approach should I use if I want to migrate a PHP/MySQL "quiz" application to a standalone project?

Tags: php, windows

I developed a PHP / MySQL based testing engine for studying purposes.  I want to migrate this functionality to a standalone application for things that cannot be published on the web publicly.

Overall, I am very fluent with PHP as a language and feel very comfortable working with it.  Can any of you suggest what some of the easier development paths are to choose from?  I thought about C#, but I think that may be overkill for what I want to do, in addition to the learning curve of the language coming from PHP (namespaces, public / private functions, etc).

tl;dr :  What's the easiest language to write a standalone windows application in if you are already familiar with PHP?

Comment: Sorry man, way too subjective. Voted to close.

Comment: stackoverflow don't give suggestions it give solutions ;)

Comment: @Brian It's not subjective really. Asker should check out http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/#work. It can be used to convert PHP to standalone Windows apps.

Comment: Well your answer to my situation would be a solution.  Different way of looking at things.

Comment: @IanAtkin How is it not subjective when the question is "what's the easiest"? As the difficulty of learning/using a particular technology depends greatly on the user, it's impossible for this to have an objective answer.

Comment: @Brian Because "the easiest" is not to recode it at all, and use a cheesy conversion tool. This removes all the evangelistic "this is the best language" arguments entirely. Now, if we were going down the "best argument" route, then sure it would be totally subjective. Sorry, just trying to give a usable answer.

Comment: His question, verbatim: "What's the easiest language to write a standalone windows application in if you are already familiar with PHP?". He didn't ask how he could automatically convert it to another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.exeoutput.com/

This will make your php  website as an executable files

Answer (score 1):

Why not run a local web server and run your tools there?  It's not on the public web, so you can keep your sensitive code offline, and you don't have to touch your code.  You can use tools like [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to quickly install all the web server tools you need on your PC.

Comment: Well, I wanted to distribute this application in its standalone form.  I know about XAMPP and EasyPHP, but I'm not sure it would fit my needs.

Comment: I wonder if you could package it all up and have a copy of your code already stashed in the htdocs folder, ready to execute?  You'd install the server tools with ready-to-run code included.  I'm guessing this gets you there with less effort than rebuilding (and testing, testing, testing) your tools in a new language.

Comment: That would really be amazing.  I'm still considering it as an option!

Comment: Good luck - I hope you find a solution that works without a pile of inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Java since it is pretty easy and MySQL is pretty easy to work with using it. Overall though, you aren't going to find a too many languages that are similar to PHP when developing desktop applications.